# Barriers to show $P=NP$

Tags: p-vs-np, barriers

We all know showing $P\ne NP$ has barriers. We all have studied these barriers because we believe $P\ne NP$.

However assume $P=NP$ and there are [wise people who believe that possibility exists](https://emanueleviola.wordpress.com/2018/02/16/i-believe-pnp/). If this is indeed the case then the very fact that we have not seen any good algorithms indicates there might be barriers in this alternate universe as well. Provability of $P\ne NP$ is barrier ridden and we do not know for sure $P\ne NP$ is the truth. We do not know for sure $P= NP$ is the truth either and so is provability of $P=NP$ also barrier ridden?

Comment: Note that natural proofs barrier assumes existence of strong psuedo-random number generators. The same assumption implies that P is not equal to NP.

Comment: As Kaveh pointed out, if P=NP, then the natural proofs barrier seems to disappear. The relativization and algebrization barriers already worked against both $P=NP$ and $P\neq NP$. So I guess the answer is: natural proofs seems not to apply, but algebrization & relativization still apply.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Are you sure that relativization still applies against $P = NP$? I thought algebrization was introduced as barrier against proving $N=NP$ (and similar problems), after work on interactive proofs showed that relativization is not really an effective barrier against proving equality.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel: Relativization definitely applies to P=NP: Baker-Gill-Solovay gave an oracle rel to which P=NP, and an oracle rel to which P$\neq$NP, which means that relativizing techniques cannot resolve the P vs NP question *in either direction*. Algebrization was introduced because the proof that IP=PSPACE (and related things like MIP=NEXP) didn't relativize.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow What is a relativizing technique for proving equality?   Does the proof that log(n)-AuxPDA equals P uses a relativizing technique? I believe that I read somewhere that there is an oracle relative to which log(n)-AuxPDA != P, but maybe this is more related to the subtleties of oracles for space bounded computations. However, for proving inequality, it is pretty obvious that most know methods relativize.

Comment: I admit that the existence of an oracle relative to which P≠NP is nice evidence in favor of P≠NP. But the obstacle towards proving P=NP is the "fact" that P≠NP. If it were indeed the case that P=NP, then there would be an algorithm, and if you know that algorithm, then the only remaining task is proving that it runs in polynomial time and solves the problem. I don't think that relativization will be a barrier against that task.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel: an example of an algebrizing technique for proving equality is the IP=PSPACE result. I believe NL=coNL relativizes. I'm sure the AUC-SPACE(poly) =PSPACE result relativizes. In fact, I'm hard-pressed to think of any equality result that doesn't either relativize or algebrize. Re: "and if you know that algorithm": if P=NP, in some sense we do, namely Levin universal search! But Levin universal search relativizes...

Comment: Actually, REG=DTIME(o(nlogn)) surely doesn't relativize, but that may have to do with the fact that REG itself seems not to relativize very well.

Comment: I don't know whether this should be considered a 'barrier' similar to those for P vs NP, but there has been some work on showing that TSP cannot be solved solved by small linear programs, which invalidated some previous attempts at showing P=NP. See [this blogpost](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/barriers-to-pnp-proofs/), for example.

Comment: There's no real barrier to just some crazy algorithm that happens to solve Boolean satisfiability. The lack of such a barrier certainly doesn't imply truth or even likelihood.

Comment: Analogously, could  the P = NP barrier have similar barriers for the VP = VNP (ie to show VP = VNP)question. In other words, what barriers could be there to show VP = VNP.

Comment: @Lance: Similarly, there's no real barrier to some crazy proof that just happens to show P$\neq$NP. It's when you try to figure out the details of what the proof will look like that things get tricky.

Answer (score 18):

Mihalis Yannakakis has shown that the traveling salesman problem cannot be solved in polynomial time by using a symmetric linear program.

See the paper [Expressing combinatorial optimization problems by Linear Programs](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002200009190024Y?via%3Dihub), by Yannakakis.

This result was [improved](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2716307) recently by  Fiorini,  Massar, Pokutta,  Tiwary, and De Wolf to drop the "symmetric" requirement in Yannakakis' result.

Comment: Preprint of Fiorini et al. is https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0837v5

Comment: The relation of the latter result to P vs. NP is discussed e.g. here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/80173/1084

Answer (score 7):

Not much of a barrier, but it's worth noting that a lot of Proof Complexity research involves finding lower bounds to the *size* of proofs of propositional statements in certain settings.

For example, there are propositions with no polynomial size tree resolution proofs (see, e.g. [these notes](https://people.clarkson.edu/%7Ealexis/PCMI/Notes/lectureA14.pdf))

This creates potential obstructions to $\mathrm{coNP} = \mathrm{NP}$, which, of course, are obstructions to $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$. E.g. one can forget about using resolution or any "classical" algorithm for SAT solving to try to find polynomial algorithms for SAT: they produce resolution proofs, which we know may be superpolynomial.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132344/discussion-on-answer-by-cody-barriers-to-show-pnp).